# Inherit from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm using several lists across my project instead of trees - for proper virtualization (a lot of items in tree structure).
Those lists are pretty much the same. The only difference is in DataTemplates. Those lists have a few events bound, which I have to copy & update in several places. Current events are used to:

- prevent horizontal auto-scrolling
- support for arrow keys to navigate through tree structure

I found no way to bind events in a single style in resource dictionary, as events must belong to specific class. So I have to copy exactly same events between classes and bind them to specific lists. That is quite a lot of text, both in XAML and code.

What I wanted to do is to define a new user control, deriving EVERYTHING from standart ListBox, but overriding a few minor methods (instead of events). And reuse this control everywhere where I need such a list without having to copy all the events.

**Problem** is - it requires me to define custom <UserControl ... />. Is there a way to just use ListBox template/style there? I need no GUI modifications from standart ListBox.

I could be missing some simple way to perform what I want. I'd  appreciate any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your setup but you will probably have to override the ListBox and ListBoxItem. Then override some methods :

```
public partial class MyListBox: ListBox
{

    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyListBoxItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is MyListBoxItem;
    }
}

public class MyListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{

}
```

This will force your containers to be ListBoxItem overrides.

Now you just have to implement yous specific code tof keys in ListBoxItem overrides. If you don't need any style changes the default ListBox style will be applied.

Now you can use it in your XAML:

```
<local:MyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <local:MyListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyListBox.ItemTemplate>
</local:MyListBox>
```

Comment: Class inheritance in code is not a problem. The problem is that I cannot use this overriden class without defining XAML UserControl for it. Visual Studio just tells me that such class is not usable in WPF. Try to put MyList onto your Window.

Comment: I've just tested it and it's all working. Can you post the precise error message from VisualStudio?

Comment: Strange, tried this in my project - and it didn't work. Tried the very same thing in blank project - and it was built finely. Thanks for help! Sorry for stupid mistake.